# Whitespace in html variable stop google maps from working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Im using googlemaps maps with a CMS. My map fails to initialize when I add the html line below (3rd line from the bottom).

```
    function addMarkerHotel(latlng, myTitle, html) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map,
            title: myTitle, 
            html: '<?php print render($content["view-cont"]); ?>',      
          }));
    }
```

If I go to view source and look at the html thats printed by the PHP I can see there are line breaks and other white space in its output:

```
    function addMarkerHotel(latlng, myTitle, html) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map,
            title: myTitle, 
            html: '<div>
                             <span> 
                                     some stuff
                             </span>
                           </div>',         
          }));
    }
```

If I remove the this whitespace and add it as plain html then the map works fine:

```
    function addMarkerHotel(latlng, myTitle, html) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map,
            title: myTitle, 
            html: '<div><span>some stuff</span></div>',         
          }));
    }
```

So, it seems the google maps javascript cant handle the whitespace that the CMS generates with the PHP. I cant change the CMSs output, so how can I make google maps tolerate / ignore the whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

It's not google maps that won't tolerate it. It's the javascript engine that breaks on new lines and won't accept that your string has an unescaped one.

Simplest solution:

```
function addMarkerHotel(latlng, myTitle, html) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: myTitle,
        html: <?php print json_encode(render($content["view-cont"])); ?>;, 
      }));
}
```

All that does is change that php string into a fully escaped javascript.

Comment: The json command prints a bunch of strange stuff that doesent resemble the content it should be"
\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n
\r\n
\r\n \r\n
Sleaford<\/span> <\/div> <\/div>\r\n <\/div>\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n<\/div> "